# (Branchless) Bitonic Sorting Network for a Set of Floating Point Numbers

Tags: algorithms, sorting, parallel-computing, floating-point, performance

In the past I've implemented a branchless Bitonic Sorting Network on a gpu using CUDA, for integers.

I am facing a related problem:

In my Order Independent Transparency implementation, I would like to employ similar sorting method in the Fragment Shader to avoid branch divergence, but the set I am using is floating point hence the bit tricks that were available in the integer implementation are not applicable(or are they, through some clever trick?).
How can I go about implementing a branchless sorting network for floats?